# Pageblock not re-rendering after button click for pagination

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, pagination

I have a VF page that lists all the records for a user:

I am trying to add pagination to the list as described by **redpoint** in [their article](http://www.redpointcrm.com/add-pagination-to-your-visualforce-pages-using-the-soql-offset-clause)

here is my VF Page code:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="navGroup" rendered="true" >
    <div class="blueBorder WidthAuto HeightAuto" id="ListRecs" >

            <div align="center">

                <apex:actionFunction action="{!refreshGrid}" name="queryByPage" reRender="navGroup,myButtons" >
                    <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectedPage}" value="" />
                </apex:actionFunction> 

                <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!navButtons}"/> 
            </div>

            <table border="1" style="width: 100%; text-align: left;"  class="ComponentTable">
                <tr style="background-color: #81d8d0;" rows="2">

                    <th style="text-align: center; width: 7%;">
                        <font class="MainPanelFont small">
                        Request
                        </font>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 23%;text-align: center;">
                        <font class="MainPanelFont small">
                            Description
                        </font>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;text-align: center;">
                        <font class="MainPanelFont small">
                            Manager
                        </font> 
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 15%;text-align: center;">
                        <font class="MainPanelFont small">
                            Created by
                        </font>
                    </th>
                    <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">
                        <font class="MainPanelFont small">
                            Status
                        </font> 
                    </th>       
                    <th style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">
                        <font class="MainPanelFont small">
                            Last Modified
                        </font> 
                    </th>                                                               
                </tr>

                <apex:repeat value="{!listRecords}" var="Requests">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-right:none; align:center;">
                            <apex:outputpanel Id="RequestID" 
                                        onmouseover="ButtonMouseOver('{!Requests.id}_RequestID');" 
                                        onmouseout="ButtonMouseOut('{!Requests.id}_RequestID');" >
                                <div id="{!Requests.id}_RequestID" class="block-link_Vsmall" >
                                    <apex:outputLink style="color: rgb(255,255,255)" value="/apex/SystemChangeRequest?mode=view&id={!Requests.id}">View</apex:outputLink>
                                </div>                                          
                            </apex:outputpanel>
                        </td>
                        <td style="border-left:none;">
                            <apex:outputText >{!Requests.Name}</apex:outputText> 
                            <br/>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Requests.Request_Title__c}" />
                            <br/>
                            (<apex:outputText value="{!Requests.recordType.Name}" />)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText style="align:left" value="{!Requests.Manager__r.Name}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText value="{!Requests.CreatedBy.Name}" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText style="align:left" value="{!Requests.Status__c}" />
                        </td>   
                        <td>
                            <apex:outputText style="align:left" value="{!Requests.Last_Modified_Date__c}" />
                            <br/>
                            <apex:outputText style="align:left" value="{!Requests.Last_Modified__c}" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>

            </table>                    
        </div>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```

Here is the part of the controller that I have added after reading the above article:

```
// return a list of records owned by the user
public list<Request_for_System_Change__c> getListRecords(){

    system.debug('getListRecords');
    system.debug('getListRecords counter='+counter);
    system.debug('getListRecords limit='+list_size);

    return [SELECT 
                id
                , Name
                , Status__c
                , Request_Title__c
                , recordType.Name
                , Manager__r.name
                , CreatedBy.name
                , Description_of_change_requested__c
                , Last_Modified_Date__c
                , Last_Modified__c 
            FROM 
                Request_for_System_Change__c
            WHERE 
                //ownerid=:userInfo.getUserID()
                Originating_Owner__c=:userInfo.getUserID() OR Manager__c=:userInfo.getUserID()
            ORDER BY 
                LastModifiedDate DESC,
                Status__c DESC
            limit :list_size
            offset :counter                                                     
            ];      
}

public integer getSizeListRequests() {
    // set the total size in the constructor

    selectedPage='0';   
    return [SELECT 
                id
                , Name
                , Status__c
                , Request_Title__c
                , recordType.Name
                , Manager__r.name
                , CreatedBy.name
                , Description_of_change_requested__c
                , Last_Modified_Date__c
                , Last_Modified__c 
            FROM 
                Request_for_System_Change__c
            WHERE 
                Originating_Owner__c=:userInfo.getUserID() OR Manager__c=:userInfo.getUserID()
            ORDER BY 
                LastModifiedDate DESC,
                Status__c DESC
            ].size();                
  }    

// List Records pagination
public Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons getnavButtons() {

    //the reRender attribute is a set NOT a string
    Set<string> theSet = new Set<string>();
    theSet.add('myPanel');
    theSet.add('myButtons');

    integer totalPages;
    if (math.mod(total_size, list_size) > 0) {
        totalPages = total_size/list_size + 1;
    } else {
        totalPages = (total_size/list_size);
    }

    integer currentPage;        
    if (selectedPage == '0') {
        currentPage = counter/list_size + 1;
    } else {
        currentPage = integer.valueOf(selectedPage);
    }

    Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons pbButtons = new Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons();        
    pbButtons.location = 'top';
    pbButtons.id = 'myPBButtons';

    Component.Apex.outputPanel opPanel = new Component.Apex.outputPanel();
    opPanel.id = 'myButtons';

    //the Previous button will alway be displayed
    Component.Apex.commandButton b1 = new Component.Apex.commandButton();
    b1.expressions.action = '{!Previous}';
    b1.title = 'Previous';
    b1.value = 'Previous';
    b1.expressions.disabled = '{!disablePrevious}';        
    b1.reRender = theSet;

    opPanel.childComponents.add(b1);        

    for (integer i=0;i<totalPages;i++) {
        Component.Apex.commandButton btn = new Component.Apex.commandButton();

        if (i+1==1) {
            btn.title = 'First Page';
            btn.value = 'First Page';
            btn.rendered = true;                                        
        } else if (i+1==totalPages) {
            btn.title = 'Last Page';
            btn.value = 'Last Page';
            btn.rendered = true;                            
        } else {
            btn.title = 'Page ' + string.valueOf(i+1) + ' ';
            btn.value = ' ' + string.valueOf(i+1) + ' ';
            btn.rendered = false;             
        }

        if (   (i+1 <= 5 && currentPage < 5)
            || (i+1 >= totalPages-4 && currentPage > totalPages-4)
            || (i+1 >= currentPage-2 && i+1 <= currentPage+2))
        {
            btn.rendered = true;
        }

        if (i+1==currentPage) {
            btn.disabled = true; 
            btn.style = 'color:blue;';
        }  

        btn.onclick = 'queryByPage(\''+string.valueOf(i+1)+'\');return false;';

        opPanel.childComponents.add(btn);

        if (i+1 == 1 || i+1 == totalPages-1) { //put text after page 1 and before last page
            Component.Apex.outputText text = new Component.Apex.outputText();
            text.value = '...';        
            opPanel.childComponents.add(text);
        } 

    }

    //the Next button will always be displayed
    Component.Apex.commandButton b2 = new Component.Apex.commandButton();
    b2.expressions.action = '{!Next}';
    b2.title = 'Next';
    b2.value = 'Next';
    b2.expressions.disabled = '{!disableNext}';        
    b2.reRender = theSet;
    opPanel.childComponents.add(b2);

    //add all buttons as children of the outputPanel                
    pbButtons.childComponents.add(opPanel);  

    return pbButtons;

}    

public PageReference refreshGrid() { //user clicked a page number        
    system.debug('**** ' + selectedPage);
    return null;
}

public PageReference Previous() { //user clicked previous button
    selectedPage = '0';
    counter -= list_size;
    return null;
}

public PageReference Next() { //user clicked next button
    selectedPage = '0';
    counter += list_size;
    return null;
}

public PageReference End() { //user clicked end
    selectedPage = '0';
    counter = total_size - math.mod(total_size, list_size);
    return null;
}

public Boolean getDisablePrevious() { //this will disable the previous and beginning buttons
    if (counter>0) return false; else return true;
}

public Boolean getDisableNext() { //this will disable the next and end buttons
    if (counter + list_size < total_size) return false; else return true;
}

public Integer getTotal_size() {
    return total_size;
}

public Integer getPageNumber() {
    return counter/list_size + 1;
}

public Integer getTotalPages() {
    if (math.mod(total_size, list_size) > 0) {
        return total_size/list_size + 1;
    } else {
        return (total_size/list_size);
    }
```

The page looks like this on load:
[image]

I can see the buttons block being re-rendered as that block is changing, but the list grid of records stays the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the guide, you need to rerender corresponding section in your page. As far as your code says next:

```
Set<string> theSet = new Set<string>();
theSet.add('myPanel');
theSet.add('myButtons');
//...
b2.reRender = theSet;
```

That mean that you are trying to rerender **apex:outputPanel** with Id **myPanel**, which does not exists.

So, to make it working, just instead of **myPanel** use  **navGroup**, which would rerender entire page block. Or add extra wrapper via **apex:outputPanel** to table.

Comment: Thanks, now I just need to center the buttons, and replace the standard command buttons with custom ones like the yellow buttons you see :)